# I can't build the next application with @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, next.js

I added a map from the documentation to my component, everything works well on the dev version, but when I try to build the project the following error occurs:

```
Type error: 'GoogleMap' cannot be used as a JSX component.
   Its instance type 'GoogleMap' is not a valid JSX element.
     The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
       Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/IT projects/tours_frontend/node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index") .ReactNode'.
         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
           Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props
```

**Component code:**

```
import style from "./Map.module.scss";
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { containerStyle, options } from "./settings";
import MapTag from "./Tag/MapTag";

interface Props {
   tags?: string[];
   center: {
     lat:number;
     lng:number;
   };
}

function Map({ tags, center }: Props) {
   const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
     id: "google-map-script",
     googleMapsApiKey: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API}`,
   });

   const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null);

   const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
     const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     setMap(map);
   }, []);

   const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
     setMap(null);
   }, []);

   return isLoaded ? (
     <div className={style["map-tab"]}>
       <div className={style["map"]}>
         <GoogleMap
           mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
           center={center}
           zoom={13}
           options={options as google.maps.MapOptions}
           onLoad={onLoad}
           onUnmount={onUnmount}
         </GoogleMap>
       </div>
       <div className={style["map-tags"]}>
         {tags?.map((tag, index) => (
           <MapTag key={index} text={tag} />
         ))}
       </div>
     </div>
   ): (
     <></>
   );
}

export default Map;
```

I looked for information about this, but found nothing. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide versions of the yarn/npm, react, and typescript packages? It's caused by version mismatching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use yarn, it is easy to fix; you just have to add the `"resolutions": {}` field to your package.json and specify the exact version of the conflicting package. This is the solution for multiple problems and can also reduce bundle size if you define any package that is duplicated in your bundle.

You should define your compatible versions. If you are updating versions, use outdated yarn. You have to update both dependencies (devDependencies) and resolutions.

In the case of npm, npm is buggy, and instead of resolutions, it uses the overrides keyword. I had no success with npm, so you are on your own here.

For similar issues and discussions, you can refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/3271).